# Groupby and filter pandas dataframe using some condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['CA', 'WA', 'CO', 'AZ'] * 3,
                   'office_id': list(range(1, 7)) * 2,
                   'sales': [np.random.randint(100000, 999999)
                             for _ in range(12)],
                       'sales2': [np.random.randint(100000, 999999)
                             for _ in range(12)]})

ls = [2, 3, 4]
```

I need to groupby the state and office_id and get the aggregated sales results for only offices whose office_id exists in the list ls

Right now, to group by state and office_id and get the sales aggregate data, I do:

```
state_office = df_test.groupby(['state', 'office_id']).agg({'sales': 'sum', 'sales2': 'sum'})
```

this gives me

```
state   office_id   sales   sales2  
AZ           2    222579    470775
             4    252315    939052
             6    835831    706745
CA           1    405711    836326
             3    710581    845048
             5    982371    704474
CO           1    404137    774343
             3    217952    270584
             5    474564    355653
WA           2    535829    410744
             4    548242    987633
             6    459783    641377
```

but I want something like the example below: the numbers were randomly generated so it wouldn't look exactly like this but just to clarify my question

```
state   office_id   sales   sales2  
AZ         2       222579   470775
CA         2       405711   836326
           3       710581   845048
CO         2       404137   774343
           4       217952   270584
WA         2       535829   410744
           3       548242   987633
```

Comment: `df_test[df_test["office_id"].isin(ls)].groupby(...`?

Comment: Thanks @Mr. T. It works! Really appreciate it.